# Angular directive as comment not working

Tags: angularjs

I'm referring AngularJS documentation, but couldn't get "Comment Directive" working the way its mentioned in fact encountered an error. Please find below details:

HTML:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/DirectiveAsComment.js"></script>
  <title>Directive as Comment</title>
 </head>
 <body ng-app="directiveAsCommentApp">
  <!-- directive:test-comment-directive -->
 </body>
</html>
```

JS:-

```
var app = angular.module('directiveAsCommentApp', []);

app.directive('testCommentDirective', function(){
 return {
        restrict: 'M',
        replace: true,
        template: 'this text is displayed because of "test-comment-directive" custom directive'
 };
});
```

Error: [$compile:tplrt] Template for directive 'testCommentDirective' must have exactly one root element.

please help me solve this issue..

Comment: This issue is because your directive uses replace: true, in that case your template have to be into a simple html tag like: template: '<div>this text is displayed because of "test-comment-directive" custom directive</div>'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the DOCs:

> When a directive is declared with `template` (or `templateUrl`) and `replace` mode on, the template must have exactly one root element. That is, the text of the template property or the content referenced by the `templateUrl` must be contained within a single html element. For example, `<p>blah <em>blah</em> blah</p>` instead of simply `blah <em>blah</em> blah`. Otherwise, the replacement operation would result in a single element (the directive) being replaced with multiple elements or nodes, which is unsupported and not commonly needed in practice.
>
> Please ref: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/tplrt

Change this

```
template: 'this text is displayed because of "test-comment-directive" custom directive'
```

to

```
template: '<div>this text is displayed because of "test-comment-directive" custom directive</div>'
```

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is with your template, write them into some tags like  or  or :
try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
     <head>
         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js">      </script>
         <title>Directive as Comment</title>
     </head>
     <body ng-app="myApp">
         <!-- directive:test-comment-directive -->
    </body>
</html>
```

and in app.js try this

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.directive('testCommentDirective', function(){
    return {
        restrict: "M",
        replace: true,
        template: "<div>this text is displayed because of 'test-comment-directive' custom directive</div>"
           };
    });
```

Comment: If you use  replace: true you have to create your template contained into simple html tag like <div> ....your template tags </div>